# Add Images For Navigation

Tags: magento-1.7, category

I'm looking to make a page similar to [This](http://www.redlightblinking.com/responsivedemo/mage16/index.php/?viewdesktop=true/) site, so each image will represent a category of items. Im just not sure where to start looking . Any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try is

1. First create a custom home page(with layout as one column) from CMS -> Pages
2. Click on content and in content area you can add images and link those images to yur category pages.
3. Make this as your home page from System -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Default Pages and select your custom home page as home page and save.